# Correct Flow types when iterating over HTMLFormElement elements?

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I have a function that takes a form element as input, filters its child elements (removing those without serializable values), then returns an object of the form `{name: value}`.

The typechecking seems to be failing because Flow is telling me that each element passed to the filter function is just a basic `HTMLElement`. I am filtering by checking `element.type`, `element.name` etc, and as `HTMLElement`s do not have these properties, there is an error.

The two filtering functions use a union type containing the relevant elements I expect to be there (`HTMLInputElement`, `HTMLTextAreaElement` etc) to typecheck. On their own these work. It is only when they are called in the filter that I get the errors.

Full code for the module is:

```
/* @flow
 * Returns form data as a javascript object. Requires each
 * form element to have a name that corresponds to its value.
 */
type FormChild =
  | HTMLInputElement
  | HTMLSelectElement
  | HTMLTextAreaElement
  | HTMLButtonElement
  | HTMLFieldSetElement;

const isValidTarget = (el: FormChild): boolean => {
  return !(el instanceof HTMLFieldSetElement) &&
         !(el instanceof HTMLButtonElement) &&
         el.name !== '';
};

const isSerializable = (el: FormChild): boolean => {
  return (el.type === 'radio' && el.checked === true) ||
         (el.type === 'checkbox' && el.checked === true) ||
         (el.type !== 'radio' && el.type !== 'checkbox');
};


export default (form: HTMLFormElement): { [elementName: string]: string } => {
  return [...form.elements].filter((el) => isValidTarget(el) && isSerializable(el))
                           .reduce((data, el) => ({ [el.name]: el.value, ...data }), {});
};
```

And the errors I am getting all refer to the call in the filter:

`HTMLElement This type is incompatible with union: HTMLInputElement | HTMLSelectElement | HTMLTextAreaElement | HTMLButtonElement | HTMLFieldSetElement`

and relating to the `reduce`:

`property 'name' Property not found in HTMLElement`

`property 'value' Property not found in HTMLElement`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two steps:

- cast type from `HTMLElement` to `FormChild`,
- remove `HTMLFieldSetElement` from `FormChild` type as it cannot have `value` attribute and will be filtered with `isValidTarget()`.

```
/* @flow
 * Returns form data as a javascript object. Requires each
 * form element to have a name that corresponds to its value.
 */
type FormChild =
  | HTMLInputElement
  | HTMLSelectElement
  | HTMLTextAreaElement;
//| HTMLButtonElement         <— removed, will be filtered by isValidTarget()
//| HTMLFieldSetElement;      <— removed, will be filtered by isValidTarget()

    const isValidTarget = (el: FormChild): boolean => {
      return !(el instanceof HTMLFieldSetElement) &&
             !(el instanceof HTMLButtonElement) &&
             el.name !== '';
    };

    const isSerializable = (el: FormChild): boolean => {
      return (el.type === 'radio' && el.checked === true) ||
             (el.type === 'checkbox' && el.checked === true) ||
             (el.type !== 'radio' && el.type !== 'checkbox');
    };


    export default (form: HTMLFormElement): { [elementName: string]: string } => {
//                                     `el: any` — prepare to cast
      return [...form.elements].filter((el: any) => isValidTarget(el) && isSerializable(el))
                               .reduce((data, el: FormChild) => ({ [el.name]: el.value, ...data }), {});
//                                           `el: FormChild` — type was casted
    };
```

Tested with flow:4.0.5

Comment: Thank you! Because the input to the filter functions could be any form element child, I was assuming I needed to include those children that would be filtered out. Your solution makes a lot of sense.